# ODAC 12c and Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, odac

Can anyone tell me if the [Oracle Data Access Components 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html) is compatible with Entity Framework 6?  The Oracle website is a nightmare for documentation and cannot find any references on how to resolve this.

I have an existing project which I am trying to upgrade to ODAC 12c and EF6 but I'm getting the following error which I am struggling to resolve:

[image: exception]

I created a fresh project to rule out any issues with my existing project and I get the same problem.  I believe it to be an issue with the app.config file edited automatically by the [Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) (Reverse Engineer Code First):

[image: config file]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: After a couple of days research, I believe that EF6 was released after ODAC 12c, so ODAC 12c & 11.2 work with EF5 but not EF6. So now I need to rollback to EF5 I guess :(

Comment: ODAC 12c Release 2 is now available but I can't see any reference to whether it supports EF6: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

Comment: I also agree Oracle's documentation is a mess

Comment: ODP.net 12 release 2 does not support EF6.  Word they gave me via twitter was summer '14.

Comment: @Jesse thanks for the update, can you link to the tweet?

Comment: https://twitter.com/OracleDOTNET/statuses/421165469681217536

Comment: Another milestone missed. Here is a slide deck from a presentation on ODAC 12c Release 2 that says it would support EF 6.

http://php.vncvr.ca/files/netbc/Oracle_NETBC_presentation.pdf

Comment: I also stumbled on the same assumption that the latest ODAC release was compatible. I was trying to set up a new EDMX through the wizard and before after setting up the connection it complains that the data provider can't work with EF6...ARRRRGGGHHH!

Comment: 12c R3 beta has been announced and sports EF6. See accepted answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Data Access Components 12c Release 3 Beta 2 **
ODAC 12c R3 is the first ODP.NET release to certify with Entity Framework (EF) 6 and EF Code First.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html

Comment: Thank you for posting the news on the new release.

Answer (score 3):

Devart recently announced [Oracle 12c support](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle-12c-support-and-more-new-features-in-new-versions-of-devart-products.html). You may want to consider using their provider instead.

Comment: This is a viable option as a paid 3rd party product. Can't understand why Oracle can get a faster iteration for their own product's support.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're receiving states that you didn't add a Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client to the providers tag.

Adding this will solve your problem:

```
<provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccessClient"
                type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

but unfortunately will not work in the end due to lack of support for EF6 in ODAC 12c R2, as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

In additional to add Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client provider to configuation/entityframework/providers tag.

```
<entityFramework>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices,Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" /></providers></entityFramework>
```

You may need to add the following DbProviderFactories tag to configuration/ because Oracle installer forgets to add it to the machine.config

```
  <system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
      type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```